Creating calculated field in Looker Studio to only show data before Today
So I want to create a new field in my report that shows me a total number of dates that have expired.
I have a column with 'End Dates' they are basically the dates that some contracts ended.
I'm trying to create a calculated field and use the TODAY function to create a formula that says, show anything where the End date is less than TODAY, but I cannot figure out the correct formula to use.
As I say I'm only looking for a total of expired dates.
Thank you.
I tried using Calculated Field with the TODAY function and the < symbol, I'm sure this combination is needed but I cannot remember how.
